# how to run unit tests for a play framework application within intellij

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, playframework

I tried running unit test on the [play framework java starter example](https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=play&project=play-java-starter-example) within intellij but it doesn't seem to work.

I downloaded the project and imported it into intellij via the SBT import.

When I tried running the tests from intellij I got "Class not found: "UnitTest"Empty test suite"

[image]

If I run the SBT test task, the tests are running and passing.

When I go bask to running the tests from intellij after running the SBT test task, the test run and pass.
It's like intellij is not compiling the project

I am working with intellij ultimate edition version 2018.2 and have the scala plugin (v 2018.2.11)

How can I make this work?

**Edit** (in respose to @hce)

I upgraded intellij to the latest version: 2018.3.2 (couldn't find 2018.3.5) but I still experience similar problems.

I started with a newly downloaded starter project.
import the sbt project:

[image]

[image]

Then tried to compile and got an error:

[image]

I managed to solve the compilation problem by configuring intellij to use the play2 compiler ("Use play2 compiler for this project")

[image]

I then tried running the tests and but intellij complains it can't find the class

[image]

this is the run configuration that was created by intellij. the class name (UnitTest) is marked red...

[image]

Is it any different in your environment?

Is there anything wrong in my process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it with IntelliJ 2018.3.5 and the Scala plugin. It works well.
So the cause  seems to be in the configuration of your project.
It would be helpful if you can provide your run/debug configuration and the settings.
There are many reasons. 
You could try the following...

- Make sure you use java 1.8 as the project jdk.
- Use sbt 1.2.1
- Check your run/debug configuration.
- File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...
- Build --> Rebuild Project
- Run --> Edit Configurations / remove Junit / Apply and restart your test. A new Junit configuration is created automatically

**Edit:** 
After the comments of @NirBrachel, the solution was to use the sbt-shell to compile the project. (I recommend clean, compile and test).

[image: sbt-shell clean, compile, test]

You could automate this during import:

[image: ![activate sbt-shell for import and build]

**Why?** 
Info: sbt compilation for play framework 2.x disabled by default

You can try to activate Play2 framework in the Settings...

[image]

WARNING: This settings didn't work for me, because it's not saved by IntelliJ.
I didn't find out yet why.

**EDIT** see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056944/intellij-play2-setting-is-not-saved/54059691#54059691) for a possible cause.

Comment: the process you outlined is working. Thanks :) bubr I don't understand why I have to go through the sbt? why doesn't intellij compile the files independently, or run the sbt compile itself. I kinda expected it to be simpler

Comment: Hi @NirBrachel, I edited the Answer once more and reduced it to the problem solution. The Why is also explained.

Comment: Thanks. this is working great. I thought the "use play 2 compiler for this project" setting should have solved this . It seems like an intellij bug

Comment: Hi @NirBrachel it seems that after closing and reopening the solution, the play2 checkbox can be set. see also my answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056944/intellij-play2-setting-is-not-saved/54059691#54059691

Comment: hi @hce. For me the problem is not saving the state of the checkbox. it is saved. but if I delete the 'target' folder and try to run the test I get the above result "Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "UnitTest"". 
Nothing is compiled.
But if I create a new Play2 run configuration, and press the Run button, then the app is compiled and ran.
This is with the checkbox set

Answer (score 0):

I use Scala plugin and Play Framework. I can run tests in 3 ways:

- simple run 1 test from IDE (but I can't run all tests in package by this way)
- run tests from sbt
- run tests with use this configuration (it's allow run tests with coverage):

Sorry for my English.

[image]