# IntelliJ Play2 setting is not saved

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework

In IntelliJ I am trying to save the following setting for the Play 2 compiler in Languages & Frameworks. But it is not saved. 
File / Settings... / Languages & Frameworks / Play 2 / activate 'Use Play 2...' / OK
And when I lookup this setting with the steps above afterwards it is not activated.

[image]

Has anyone an idea why it is not saved?

**additional Info:**

I imported the [play-java-starter-example](https://developer.lightbend.com/start/?group=play&project=play-java-starter-example) with IntelliJ.
IntelliJ gives Info: Play2 framework disabled by default.
So I tried to activate the Play 2 compiler as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that...

This strange behavior seems to be an IntelliJ bug.
I am using IntelliJ 2018.3.2 on a Window 10 OS.

The first time the project is imported from starter-sample, the Play2 checkbox is not saved in IntelliJ.

After closing and reopening the solution, the Play2 checkbox can be set and saved.